# TextChanged event fires but does not run in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, textchanged

In my aspx file I have the following code:

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phdHolding" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phdInput" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <h3><asp:Label ID="lblArea" runat="server" Text="Area" /></h3>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In code behind (c#) I create a table which is added to phdInput.  One part of that code is the creation and population of a TextBox (and Label) within a Table Cell.  The TextBox is required to call a function on TextChanged.

```
     decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(dc.DataScalar("SELECT Item" + rownr + " FROM Companies WHERE CompanyName='" + coy + "' AND BusinessUnit='" + bu + "'"));
     TextBox tb = new TextBox(); tb.ID = "txtAmount" + rownr; tb.Width = 70; tb.Text = amount.ToString("N0");
     tb.AutoPostBack = true; tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(UpdateAmounts);
     Label lbl = new Label(); lbl.Text= " " + trow["Unit"].ToString();
     TableCell tdamount = new TableCell(); tdamount.Controls.Add(tb); tdamount.Controls.Add(lbl); 
     tr2.Cells.Add(tdamount);
```

This is all working fine and everything is displayed on the page.  However, when the text is changed and you click outside the textbox or press'Enter' etc. the function is not being reached (have checked in VS) and phdInput becomes blank.

I have used this function, and the TextChanged method of calling it, before with no issues so why is it not working now?

Comment: Could you show us definition of `tr2` and the moment when you add `tr2` to the form?

Comment: For the firrst cell in the row:
     int rownr = Convert.ToInt32(trow["Srl"].ToString());
     TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(); tr2.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
       TableCell tdtype = new TableCell(); tdtype.Text = trow["Type"].ToString(); tdtype.Width = 250;
                    tdtype.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
          tr2.Cells.Add(tdtype);

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to recreate **one** problem

> phdInput becomes blank

This was suspicious, if it disappears there must be `PostBack` in the action. Suspicion rises especially because `phdInput` attribute `Visible` is set to `false` on the form.

I suppose form's initialization is happening inside the `Page_Load` method and one of the code behind lines is to set `phdInput` attribute `Visible` to `true`. However, `phdInput` disappears after `PostBack` is fired, so there's probably check

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

Initialization is happening inside of it, which is correct, no need to initialize it every time page reloads. However

```
phdInput.Visible = true;
```

should be outside of check `if (!IsPostBack)` in order to `phdInput` be always visible.

Next, something fires the `PostBack`.

> **However, when the text is changed and you click outside the textbox or**
>   **press'Enter' etc.** the function is not being reached (have checked in
>   VS) and **phdInput becomes blank.**

This sounds like `TextChanged` event works, it only calls some other event handler.

I hope it will help you find the solution. Here follows the code that recreates the issue *phdInput becomes blank* (it is poorly written).

**.aspx** - content of `body` tag

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>start</p>

        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phdHolding" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phdInput" runat="server" Visible="false" >
                <h3><asp:Label ID="lblArea" runat="server" Text="Area" /></h3>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>

        <p>end</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication8
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    // row 1
                    int rownr = Convert.ToInt32(1);
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    tr.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                    TableCell tdtype = new TableCell();
                    tdtype.Text = "table cell 1 text";
                    tdtype.Width = 250;
                    tdtype.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                    tr.Cells.Add(tdtype);

                    decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(1);
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox(); tb.ID = "txtAmount" + rownr; tb.Width = 70; tb.Text = amount.ToString("N0");
                    tb.AutoPostBack = true; tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(UpdateAmounts);
                    Label lbl = new Label(); lbl.Text = " " + "1";
                    TableCell tdamount = new TableCell(); tdamount.Controls.Add(tb); tdamount.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    tr.Cells.Add(tdamount);

                    // row 2
                    int rownr2 = Convert.ToInt32(2);
                    TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
                    tr2.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                    TableCell tdtype2 = new TableCell();
                    tdtype2.Text = "table cell 2 text";
                    tdtype2.Width = 250;
                    tdtype2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                    tr2.Cells.Add(tdtype2);

                    decimal amount2 = Convert.ToDecimal(2);
                    TextBox tb2 = new TextBox(); tb2.ID = "txtAmount" + rownr2; tb2.Width = 70; tb2.Text = amount2.ToString("N0");
                    tb2.AutoPostBack = true; tb2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(UpdateAmounts);
                    Label lbl2 = new Label(); lbl2.Text = " " + "2";
                    TableCell tdamount2 = new TableCell(); tdamount2.Controls.Add(tb2); tdamount2.Controls.Add(lbl2);
                    tr2.Cells.Add(tdamount2);

                    // table
                    var table = new Table();
                    table.Rows.Add(tr);
                    table.Rows.Add(tr2);
                    phdInput.Controls.Add(table);

                    lblWarning.Text = "some warning";
                    lblArea.Text = "some area text";

                    lblWarning.Visible = true;
                    phdInput.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected void UpdateAmounts(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**when page is opened**

[image]

**after *textbox*'s text is changed** - either one

[image]